# NodeJS Redirecting WIth Single-Page JQuery Mobile

Tags: node.js, jquery-mobile, express

I'm working on a NodeJS/ExpressJS application using JQuery Mobile (JQM).  I'm having trouble redirecting from the backend.  My app dynamically generates buttons

`<button class=\"setAttndingbtn btn btn-primary\" value=\"" + curr.place_id + "\">Attending: " + numAttending.numAttnd + " people are going</button>`

after a $.getJSON search is made.  Using promises/setTimeout, the following handler is attached to all buttons:

```
$('.setAttndingbtn').click(function(){
  var buttonsir = $(this);    //Store this button reference  
  if($(this).html().slice(0,1) == 'A'){  //Check the button's state
       $.getJSON('/api/attending/' + $(this).val(), function(data){ //Ajax
             $(buttonsir).text("You are attending! " + data.numAttnd + " people are going"); //Change state
                       });
  } else {
       $.getJSON('/api/attending/rmv/' + $(this).val(), function(data){
             $(buttonsir).text("Attending: " + data.numAttnd + " people are going");
                        });
                    } 
                });
```

The relevant routes are here:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
}

  app.route('/login')
  .get(function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(p + "/public/login.html");
  });

  app.route('/api/attending/:number')
  .get(isLoggedIn, searchServerInstance.setAttending);
```

On the backend, when an "Attending" button is clicked, I want to check if the user is logged in and if not, redirect them to the login page.  When I run the code as is, in Firefox's Firebug console, I see the GET request and if I expand it, in the "Response" section, the HTML code to my login page is displayed.  But the page doesn't actually load the file.

My /login.html has `<div data-role="page">`, header, and content tags, as JQM recommends. I've tried including the entire login page in my /index.html, but attempting to use `res.redirect("/public/index.html#page2")` results in a "file not found".

Is it possible to use Node/Express to tell JQM which `<div data-role="page" id="page1">` to load?  Is there a way to force JQM to load /login.html from the server-side, the way `rel="external"` allows for?  Or will I have to ditch JQM?

Comment: How about directly sending the file in the else section where redirect things is done. Please check.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite I just tried 'isLoggedIn(){...} else { res.sendFile(p + '/public/login.html')} and had the same problem, the console shows the HTML file as in the GET response, but the page does not load it.

Comment: So I guessed xD. What are you using at the front end?

Comment: JQuery Mobile has the biggest impact.  But there's also jquery, jquery ui, and bootstrap's js and css files included in the head of the /index.html page.  /login.html has bootstrap-social and font-awesome in the data-role="header".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through the JQM documentation, I've figured out some ways to do this.  For anyone else who encounters it, here's what I believe I understand:

1. If you don't care about maintaining the integrity of the single-page, you can look into turning off [JQM's defaults](https://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/), like `ajaxEnabled`, which turns off JQM's hash listening and ajax, loading URLs normally. I don't know if this works with Express's res.redirect because I haven't tried it.
2. What I opted to do was to replace `res.redirect('/login.html')` with a custom JSON response `res.send({loginState: "LOGIN"})`.  Then, on the client side, within my `$.getJSON` request in the `$('.setAttndngbtn')` listener, i put the following code:

.

```
if(data.loginstate !== "LOGIN"){
          $(buttonsir).text("You are attending! " + data.numAttnd + " people are going");
} else {
          $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", '#page2');
}
```

And it works just fine!  Here is the JQM documentation on the pagecontainer widget that allows in-page redirection with the `change` method or external redirection with the `load` method.